# seaborn barplot of pivot table - data must be 1-dimensional

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm just starting on python and am trying to use seaborn to plot a dataframe created using a pivot table.  I understand the values I'm trying to use as the y value is a multiindex array but I don't know what to do to get around it.  Matplotlib plots the dataframe without any issue.  Is there a way to do this in seaborn or is the answer "It works with matplotlib, use that dummy!"?

Here's the pivot table.

```
#make a pivot table for graph to display fiscal year, month, sum of sales (without Totals - totals mess up the graph)
#pivotFY21graph_df = eventsFY21_df.pivot_table(index = ["fiscal_year", "fiscal_month", "Month"], columns = "Booking_Status", 
pivotFY21graph_df = eventsFY21_df.pivot_table(index = ["Month"], columns = "Booking_Status", 
                                 values = "Rack Rental", aggfunc = "sum")
#format each sum value to be 0 if null
pivotFY21graph_df["Contract"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
pivotFY21graph_df["Covid19"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
pivotFY21graph_df["Definite"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
pivotFY21graph_df["T1"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
pivotFY21graph_df["T2"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
pivotFY21graph_df["CXLD"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
#format each Booking_Status sum
pivotFY21graph_df.style.format({"CXLD": "${:20,.2f}", 
                           "Contract": "${:20,.2f}",
                           "Covid19": "${:20,.2f}",
                           "Definite": "${:20,.2f}",
                           "T1": "${:20,.2f}",
                           "T2": "${:20,.2f}"})
```

The error from trying to use bar plot.

```
    sns.barplot(x = pivotFY21graph_df.index.values, y = pivotFY21graph_df.values, 
    data = pivotFY21graph_df)
```

error message:

```
~\Anaconda3\envs\city_work\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py in sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
    480     elif subarr.ndim > 1:
    481         if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
--> 482             raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")
    483         else:
    484             subarr = com.asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please post your code as text rather than as images - this makes it much easier for the community to help

Comment: Sorry and thanks.  Is that better?

Comment: This is better, thanks for updating.  Best is to provide an example that users could run themselves ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)].  I don't know the issue here, but upvoting